# How to pad the sequence in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, sequence, pad

I have a Dataset that contains ragged tensors like this:

```
non_ragged_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 5, 3, 2, 8])
non_ragged_dataset = non_ragged_dataset.map(tf.range)
batched_non_ragged_dataset = non_ragged_dataset.apply(
    tf.data.experimental.dense_to_ragged_batch(2))
for element in batched_non_ragged_dataset:
    print(element)
----output----
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]>
```

Each RaggedTensor means a sequence and the shape is (None, None). I want to transform the sequence to length=5, i.e. shape=(5, None) like this:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0], [0], [0]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0], [0], [0]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0], [0], [0], [0]]>
```

Is there any ways? Thanks all!

Comment: I don't understand the transformation you want to perform. The first ragged tensor has been added 2 `[0]` rows, so now it has 4 rows. The second has been added 3, to get 5 rows, and the last one 4, to get 5 rows. I don't understand how this is related to `length=10`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will fix it

Comment: I have try using the padded_batch function many times but all failed T_T: `dataset.padded_batch(batch_size=2, padded_shapes=(5, None), padding_values=[0])` or `dataset.padded_batch(batch_size=2, padded_shapes=(5, None), padding_values=0)` or `dataset.padded_batch(batch_size=2, padded_shapes=5, padding_values=[0])` or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate the necessary number of rows to each ragged tensor:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def pad_ragged_arrays(length):
    def transform(r):
        pad_size = tf.math.maximum(length - r.nrows(), 0)
        return tf.concat([r, tf.zeros([pad_size, 1], dtype=r.dtype)], axis=0)
    return transform

length = 5
dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 5, 3, 2, 8])
           .map(tf.range)
           .apply(tf.data.experimental.dense_to_ragged_batch(2))
           .map(pad_ragged_arrays(length)))
for element in dataset:
    print(element)
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0], [0], [0]]>
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0], [0], [0]]>
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0], [0], [0], [0]]>
```